# Ionic App Breaks With PHP Scripts

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

I followed [this Lynda tutorial](http://www.lynda.com/AngularJS-tutorials/Building-Mobile-App-AngularJS-1-Ionic/368920-2.html?srchtrk=index%3A1%0Alinktypeid%3A2%0Aq%3Aionic%0Apage%3A1%0As%3Arelevance%0Asa%3Atrue%0Aproducttypeid%3A2) to get a working Ionic App, and I also followed [this Lynda tutorial](http://www.lynda.com/MySQL-tutorials/PHP-MySQL-Essential-Training/119003-2.html) to set up a MySQL backend with some PHP scripts (I highly recommend both tutorials, by the way!). Now I am trying to get my Ionic app connected to my MySQL database.

The Ionic app currently grabs data from `js/data.json`, which is just JSON data 
In `app.js`:

```
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state',
    function($scope, $http, $state) {
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.artists = data.artists;
    });
}]);
```

I wrote a PHP script that displays the exact same thing as `data.json`. I thought this would be a good first step towards bridging the gap between the two tutorials. 
in `Load_Data.php`:

```
 $response = "";
 //omitting code where I fill $response with all 
 //the same info as data.json

 $json = json_encode($response);
 printf("%s", $json);
```

I have compared the outputs of `data.json` and `Load_Data.php` and they are indeed identical. I have also used [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to make sure that it is valid json. However, replacing `js/data.json` with `js/Load_Data.php` just makes all the data disappear with no console or server errors.

Also, when I try to go directly to `js/Load_Data.php` from the url, I immediately get redirected back to `index.html`, and the browser downloads the file instead of running it. I have no idea why this happens, because I have *no* code in that file other than encoding and printing the json data.

How can I fix my code so my Ionic app can access my MySQL database?

Comment: Maybe you have to [set the Content-type header to application/json](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4064468/3585500).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with this:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);    
$scope.artists = data.artists;
```

It is parsing the `data` before using it as a JSON object.